# How to add a class in yii form button submit

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, yii

This is a code for a form. I want to add a class for submit button and add a inline style for all text fields. How can I do this one?

for example in view source look like this 

I want to edit like this

```
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'login-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
        <p class="hint">
            Hint: You may login with <kbd>demo</kbd>/<kbd>demo</kbd> or <kbd>admin</kbd>/<kbd>admin</kbd>.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="row rememberMe">
        <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->label($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try read manual or docs, or see examples

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'username', array('class' => 'myText', 'style' => 'width: 320px; border-radius: 10px;')); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login', array('class' => 'submitClass', 'style' => 'width: 120px; border-radius: 10px;')); ?>
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#submitButton-detail

Answer (score 1):

very simple just add an array,in it you can put any html attribute in it

Like

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('class'=>'your class name','id'=>'Any Id You want to insert')); ?>
```